# Django: Executing multiple commands with checkboxes

Tags: python, django

In my template I have two different tables. Table 1 shows every records with status "Yes". Table 2 shows records with status "No".

Each row of table 1 has a button which changes the database status from "Yes"to "No". Meaning that if the user clicks the button, the record will move from table 1 to table 2. Table 2 has the same function, but then the other way around.

I have now added a checkbox to do the same thing but then which multiple records. It all works, except in one scenario. When the first table is empty, I am unable to move items from table 2 to 1 with the checkbox function.

**The two tables**

```html
  <form action="{% url 'complete_multiple_tasks'%}" method="POST">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <table class="trainers-table" id="myTable2">
                                
                                    <tr>
                                        <th> <button id = "deletion"class="btn_delete" type="submit" name="checkboxsubmit"> Uitvoeren</button></th>
                                        <th> Taak</th>
                                        <th> Check?</th>
                                        <th> Voltooien</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    {% for todo_nee in todo_nee%}
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="instance" value={{todo_nee.id}} id="delete_selected">
                                        </td>
                                    </form>
                                        <td> {{todo_nee.name}}</td>
                                        <td> <i id= "nocheck" class="fas fa-times-circle"></i></td>
                                        <td><form action="{% url 'todo_compleetmaken' todo_nee.id %}" method=POST>
                                            {% csrf_token %}
                                            <input type="hidden" name="returntopage" value="{{ request.path }}">
                                            <button class="paginationformat2" type="submit">Uitvoeren</button>
                                            </form>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    {%endfor%}
                            </table>
                       
                    </div>
    
                   
                        
                        <form action="{% url 'oncomplete_multiple_tasks'%}" method="POST">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <table class="trainers-table" id="myTable2">
                                
                                <tr>
                                <th> <button id = "deletion"class="btn_delete" type="submit"> Ongedaan</button></th>

                                <th> Taak</th>
                                <th> Check?</th>
                                <th> Onvoltooien</th>
                                <th> Gebruiker</th>
                                </tr>
                                {% for todo_ja in todo_ja%}
                                <tr>     
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="instance" value={{todo_ja.id}} id="delete_selected">
                                    </td>      
                                </form>       
                                    <td> {{todo_ja.name}}</td>
                                    <td> <i id= "check"class="fas fa-check-circle"></i></td>
                                    <td> <form action="{% url 'todo_oncompleetmaken' todo_ja.id %}" method=POST>
                                        {% csrf_token %}
                                        <input type="hidden" name="returntopage" value="{{ request.path }}">
                                        <button class="paginationformat2" type="submit">Ongedaan</button>
                                        </form> 
                                    </td>
                                    <td> {{todo_ja.user}}</td>
                                </tr>
                                {%endfor%}
                            </table>
```

Essentially, this action isnt carried out when the left table is empty: .

**View which either completes or incompletes multiple tasks**

```
@login_required
def complete_multiple_tasks(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': #<- Checking for method type
        id_list = request.POST.getlist('instance')
        for instance in id_list:
            todo = Todo.objects.get(id=instance)
            todo.complete = "Ja"
            todo.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/'))
    context = {}
    return render(request,'kalender/empty.html',context)

@login_required
def oncomplete_multiple_tasks(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': #<- Checking for method type
        id_list = request.POST.getlist('instance')
        for instance in id_list:
            todo = Todo.objects.get(id=instance)
            todo.complete = "Nee"
            todo.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/'))
    context = {}
    return render(request,'kalender/empty.html',context)
```

It appears to work in every situation, but not if the left table has 0 records, and you want to move records from the right to the left table. If anyone sees why this happens, please let me know!

Comment: It looks like you are only changing the `complete` status here - can you share your code where the `todo` instances swap tables?

Comment: Hey Daniel thanks for your response. Basically the left table has a query which shows all records where complete ="Nee" and the right table has a query which shows all the records where complete ="Ja". So all that the checkboxes do is changing the complete status, which then makes them show up in the other table due to the status change. First table has query todo_nee, which is todo.objects.filter(complete="Nee"). The second table has query todo_ja, which is todo.objects.filter(complete="Ja").